# Spark Streaming: how to get processing time and scheduling delay by StreamingListener?

Tags: spark-streaming

The offical documentation says we can get the values of processing time by StreamingListener:　The progress of a Spark Streaming program can also be monitored using the StreamingListener interface, which allows you to get receiver status and processing times.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#monitoring-applications

I know there is some information about the metrics of Spark, but it does not contains the processing time and scheduling delay.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

I read the source code of StreamingListener． It contains a method like this:

```
def printStats() {
    showMillisDistribution("Total delay: ", _.totalDelay)
    showMillisDistribution("Processing time: ", _.processingDelay)
}
```

I think it is possible to get these metrics but I did not realize it.
I need these metrics for my research. How can I get them?  Thanks very very much．

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

```
class MyListener() extends StreamingListener {
    override def onBatchCompleted(batchStarted: StreamingListenerBatchCompleted) {
    println("Total delay: " + batchStarted.batchInfo.totalDelay)
    println("Processing time: " + batchStarted.batchInfo.processingDelay)
  }
}
```